# ASP.NET Post to URL Asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, post, asynchronous

From my ASP.NET application I want to do a HTTP POST to some other url Asynchronously. How can I do this? Is there some out-of-the box method to do this?

Comment: Using StackExchange as search engine.

Comment: Googling [.NET HTTP POST Asynchronous](https://www.google.com/search?q=.NET+HTTP+POST+Asynchronous) answers this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you are trying to do, but you should look into the **WebClient** class.

If you need to post a string, there's the [UploadStringAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144240%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) async method.